# How can I: Replace all instances of an old 'base' href on archived website with a new one for quick changeover?

Tags: javascript, php, image, replace, hyperlink

This problem has come up before for me. I had to manually (or using search/replace in an HTML editor) ***replace all instances*** of `EXAMPLE.COM` with `MYTESTSERVER.COM/EXAMPLE` for sake of links/images not being broken (This includes any values for HREF or SRC properties--especially these types, actually).

The site was made in 2012... it does include template files (WordPress theme I developed painstakingly over the course of 5-6 months). The template files aren't really what I'm concerned with... it's the countless references to the old domain that was used within the "post" files...

This was an "Online Literary Journal", so there's enough supporting graphics spread throughout the individual posts' code to make me want to find a script to stick in the header.php or footer.php which will change this all over for me on each browser load, without me having to alter the code much (at least for the time being while this is still an "archived" client site)...
THANKS!

NOTE: I am NOT actually using any kind of `<BASE>` coding... as in building links through the structure of the site's code based on a single instance of a base href. This site was one of my first WordPress projects, and furthermore one of my first "dynamic-like" sites... so I also did not utilize WordPress' php function of `bloginfo()`... WISH I HAD NOW LOOKING BACK!

**also now i realize that using PHP code within posts isn't the easiest thing to do... nor was it then, so the links were coded as static.

Comment: I've tried all kinds of methods... including (and unfortunately not understanding) how to manipulate the DOM text with scripts written for find/replace techniques.  It seems that either I cannot get this particular script to do what I need it to do or that I am attempting to use something that will not work for me regardless of my limited javascript knowledge.

Comment: REALLY? Someone down-voted my question without even bothering to leave feedback? Real classy.

Answer (score 0):

Download the site to your local machine

#### Use Sublime Text:

- Press `cmd + shift + F` / `ctrl + shift + F` (Win)
- Select the `...` symbol & Choose add folder
- Choose your folder and do your 'global' search and replace.

[image]

---

*Note: Might be a good time to entertain using partials and setting up light static site generator to make this work easier going forward*

Comment: I completely agree, I know this now after primarily working with WordPress for the past 4 years or so now... however I was trying to avoid your method.  I will probably use this, because it seems that holding out for a scripted method might not work out too soon, but we'll see.

Comment: jbalesteri, what about just downloading the .SQL file from phpMyAdmin... could I simply perform a search/replace on the Database in a more efficient process (download -> find/replace -> save -> replace database tables)???

Comment: because I'm not worried about the template files for now... I will manually need to update them anyways (if my client wants to actually restore this to a proper domain, and not just my testing domain).  This is where I will also implement the `bloginfo()` function that will just generate the appropriate site path wherever the site's files are hosted.